# AWS SNS generated from Alert to Terminate an Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I am not that familiar with using Lambda and was wondering if anyone could provide guidance to the following scenario.

I would like to create a lambda function that is called via SNS subscription when an alert is fired for an instance where its CPU is >=100 percent.

I have already created the Alert, SNS topic ect.. what I am looking for now is the lambda code that will get the instance and terminate said instance.

Anyone have code to perform this action?

Thanks!

Comment: The CloudWatch information is sent to SNS, which will pass the data to the Lambda function via the event. Simply send the `event` to the Lambda log and then you can see the data that is being passed. Then, you can extract the Instance ID and call `TerminateInstance`.

Answer (score 2):

If all that you want to do is to terminate the instance based on the CPU utilization then you dont need AWS Lambda for that. You can simply do that using [Amazon CloudWatch Alarms](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/UsingAlarmActions.html) as follows

1. Open the CloudWatch console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/.
2. In the navigation pane, choose Alarms, Create Alarm.
3. For the Select Metric step, do the following:

   1. Under EC2 Metrics, choose Per-Instance Metrics.
   2. Select the row with the instance and the CPUUtilization metric.
   3. For the statistic, choose Average.
   4. Choose a period (for example, 1 Hour).
   5. Choose Next.
4. For the Define Alarm step, do the following:

   1. Under Alarm Threshold, type a unique name for the alarm (for example, Terminate EC2 instance) and a description of the alarm (for example, Terminate EC2 instance when CPU is idle for too long). Alarm names must contain only ASCII characters.
   2. Under Whenever, for is, choose < and type 10. For for, type 24 consecutive periods.
   3. Under Notification, for Send notification to, choose an existing SNS topic or create a new one.
   4. To create an SNS topic, choose New list. For Send notification to, type a name for the SNS topic (for example, Terminate_EC2_Instance). For Email list, type a comma-separated list of email addresses to be notified when the alarm changes to the ALARM state. Each email address is sent a topic subscription confirmation email. You must confirm the subscription before notifications can be sent to an email address.
   5. Choose EC2 Action.
   6. For Whenever this alarm, choose State is ALARM. For Take this action, choose Terminate this instance.
   7. Choose Create Alarm.